# Swift Command Line tool needs other file

Tags: swift, command-line-interface

So I have a script that takes an input and prints whatever. It needs access to a file written by a third party. My Xcode project structure is just two files, main.swift and ThirdParty.swift. If I just run it from Xcode main.swift happily sees ThirdParty.swift and I'm apply to instantiate an object defined within. When I run from the command line it cannot find ThirdParty.swift (which is pretty much to be expected; how would it know it's there?).

None of the command line options to pass to /usr/bin/swift seem to be appropriate for pointing to a file I'd like to use and pointing it to the current directory doesn't work either. Is this even possible or should I just give up?

The ideal end result is the ability to do something like:

```
./main.swift --option1 --option2 thing
```

But an acceptable place to end up would be:

```
swift -X ThirdParty.swift main.swift --option1 --option2 thing
```

Where X is whatever option I need to be passing in.

Comment: can you please include the outputs of: ln -ls ThirdParty_file ; id ? Are all the files in the same directory you run in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass two files into "immediate" mode (`swift` REPL mode) but you have several other options:

1. Combine the files together on the fly into a temporary file (with e.g. `/bin/cat`)
2. Compile the two files into a normal binary with `swiftc`.

I recommend option 2, though it means every time you change the code you'll need to recompile, and the binaries it creates aren't portable between OS X and Linux.

Comment: Option two worked like a charm. Thanks for your help.